# Is there any way to use Javascript's Array.map function to return the object + new key value pair added to it

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype

What i want to accomplish is to map the objects of array to add one more key value pair.

For example:

```js
var arr = [{    "name": "ABC",    "id": 1    },
{    "name": "XYZ",    "id": 2    },
{    "name": "QWE",    "id": 3    }];

var arr2 = arr.map( x => x.id_name = x.id + ' - ' + x.name);

console.log('arr = ', arr);
console.log('arr2 = ',arr2);
```

It changes the original array as expected, but returns an array of x.id_name only.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to **change original array**, use [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
let arr = [{"name": "ABC","id": 1},{"name": "XYZ","id": 2},{"name": "QWE","id": 3}];

arr.forEach( x => x.id_name = x.id + ' - ' + x.name);
console.log(arr);
```

If you want to **preserve original array**, use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
let arr = [{"name": "ABC","id": 1},{"name": "XYZ","id": 2},{"name": "QWE","id": 3}];

let arr1 = arr.map(({id,name}) => ({id, name, "id_name" : id + ' - ' + name}));
console.log(arr1); // udpated
console.log(arr); // same
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to return the entire object:

```
arr.map(x => {
  x.id_name = x.id + ' - ' + x.name
  return x
})
```

Or more elegant, as this does not modify the original array:

```
add.map(({id, name}) => ({
  id,
  name,
  id_name: `${id} - ${name}`
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

With a new property of the same object, you mutate it by assinging a value.

You need a new object without a reference to the old object by using [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and map this object.

```js
var array = [{ name: "ABC", id: 1 }, { name: "XYZ", id: 2 }, { name: "QWE", id: 3 }],
    newArray = array.map(o => Object.assign({}, o, { id_name: [o.id, o.name].join(' - ') }));

console.log(newArray);
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do

```
arr.map(elem => ({...elem, ['id_name']: `${elem.id}-${elem.name}`}))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = arr.map(function(x) { return { name: x.name, test: 'bob' + x.name } });
```

That should get you on the way

Answer (score 0):

From your implementation, you told `map` to return the `x.id_name`. As with arrow functions, you can return from it in two ways

**directly with a single return**

```
array.map(item => single_line_expression)
  // example
  [1,2,3,4].map(n => n*4)
  result :
    [4, 8, 12, 16]
```

**block statements**

```
array.map(item => {
  statements 
  return what_should_be_replace_by_item
})

// example
[1,2,3,4].map(n => {
  const multi = n*4
  return multi
})
result :
 [4, 8, 12, 16]
```